# Java annotation for commented out code

Tags: java, annotations, refactoring

So like probably many people out there I usually comment out code temporarily, mostly for debugging purposes. I currently put something like **DEBUG** or whatever that is easily searched for, but I thought having the compiler output a warning (or even an error) whenever it finds code that is temporarily commented out could be useful. I thought of using an annotation, but annotations can't be used to mark comments.

Does anyone know of a better approach than putting an easily searchable string in the commented-out section of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least Eclipse allows you to use (and define your own) markers put in comments, that can be easily listed afterwards. There's at least TODO and XXX, but I believe you could make your own as well.

Answer (score 4):

there are plenty of code inspection tools out there that can alert you to the presence of code patterns that you define. most of them have built-in support for detecting common stuff like "//todo" comments left in code etc.

most IDEs support auto-detection of //todo as well (intellij idea, for example).

a common command-line tool for this is [checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/). you could run it as part of your build and have it point these things out to you

Comment: Just to add: it's possible to integrate checkstyle with build management tools. In Maven, you could let a build fail if a checkstyle rule is violated, just warn the developer or behave differently depending on the active profiles (e.g. `dev` and `prod`).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Maven, consider to use the [taglist-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/taglist-maven-plugin/).